# LINQ WPF Binding with Cross-Thread Collection Changed Notification

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, data-binding

So, I've spent a good amount of time using ContinuousLinq to bind collections to WPF using LINQ in my client app. Now I get to testing and find out that ComboBoxes do not support collection change notifications cross-thread.

Does anyone know of a Bindable LINQ solution that has an option to force change event to be raised on a given UIThread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ContinuousLinq is open source, you could modify it to add this behavior...

Here's [an example](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) of how to do it with an `ObservableCollection`. You could probably use the same principle for ContinuousLinq.

Comment: I'm a VB.Net coder so I'm a slow reader of C# and an even worse writer. I sis find another simple example of how to override the ObservableCollection but I just cant get one part to work in VB

Basically, I GetInvocationList of the CollectionChanged event but cannot figure out how to do this in VB.

Dim eventHandler As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler = CollectionChanged

Comment: Is what I translated the C# to but this line gives me an error saying that CollectionChanged is an event and cannot be called directly. How can I get the invocation list of an event in VB.NET?

Comment: Ok, I just went with your first suggestion. I found the area in ContinuousLinq that raises the events and found that it was in fact already using a Dispatcher that was assigned from teh thread that instantiated the collection. I added a property to the collection that would allow me to set my own dispatcher. 

Thanks for the advice Tom.

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, I was asleep... Anyway, it seems you found the solution ;)